# Brew Tap: Authentication failed

Tags: git, github, homebrew

Env: Mac Bash, 
When I tried to tap into a repo ( at first an organisation repo, then my own private repo, all got the same auth failed error):

It seems like wrong user name and password. However I used exactly the user name and password when I log into Github. I confirmed several times. Could someone enlighten me what is wrong here?

```
==> Tapping <my repo name>
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/<my user name>/homebrew-<my repo name>'...
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://github.com': <my github user name>
Password for 'https://<my user name>@github.com':
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<my user name>/homebrew-<my repo name>'
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/<my user name>/homebrew-<my repo name> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/<my user name>/homebrew-<my repo name> --depth=1` exited with 128.
```

Comment: That's not a programming question but one about the use of some software. As such, it is more suitable to e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: What does `which git-credential-osxkeychain` say?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue with the following command : brew install mongodb

- brew is checking in github.

It was fixed adding the precise version to install:

- brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.2